# Google Sheets Query Function - Nested OR function among ands

Tags: google-sheets

I posted a question yesterday and pulling tons of data from a table using sumifs function; however, I've figured *most* of it out. I've switched the formula to a query. Right now, my formula looks like this:

```
=query(B:AK,"SELECT C,F,I,M,O,P,S,U,Y,AC,AJ,AK

WHERE C <> '"&AP8&"' 
and C <> '"&AP12&"'
and C <> '"&AP2&"'
and C <> '"&AP3&"'
and C <> '"&AP4&"'
and C <> '"&AP5&"'
and C <> '"&AP6&"'
and C <> '"&AP7&"'
and C <> '"&AP9&"'
and C <> '"&AP10&"'
and C <> '"&AP11&"'
and C <> '"&AP13&"'
and C <> '"&AP14&"'
and C <> '"&AP15&"'
and C <> '"&AP16&"'
and C <> '"&AP17&"'
and C <> '"&AP18&"'
and C <> '"&AP19&"'
and C <> '"&AP20&"'
and C <> '"&AP21&"'
and C <> '"&AP22&"'
and C <> '"&AP23&"'
and C <> '"&AP24&"'
and C <> '"&AP25&"'
and C <> '"&AP26&"'
and C <> '"&AP27&"'
and C <> '"&AP28&"'
and C <> '"&AP29&"'
and C <> '"&AP30&"'
and C <> '"&AP31&"'
and C <> '"&AP32&"'
and C <> '"&AP33&"'
and C <> '"&AP34&"'
and C <> '"&AP35&"'
and C <> '"&AP36&"'
and C <> '"&AP37&"'
and C <> '"&AP38&"'
and C <> '"&AP39&"'
and C <> '"&AP40&"'
and C <> '"&AP41&"'
and C <> '"&AP42&"'
and C <> '"&AP43&"'
and C <> '"&AP44&"'
and C <> '"&AP45&"'
and C <> '"&AP46&"'
and C <> '"&AP47&"'
and C <> '"&AP48&"'
and C <> '"&AP49&"'
and C <> '"&AP50&"'
and C <> '"&AP51&"'
and C <> '"&AP52&"'
and C <> '"&AP53&"'
and C <> '"&AP54&"'
and C <> '"&AP55&"'
and C <> '"&AP56&"'
and C <> '"&AP57&"'
and C <> '"&AP58&"'
and C <> '"&AP59&"'
and C <> '"&AP60&"'
and C <> '"&AP61&"'
and C <> '"&AP62&"'
and C <> '"&AP63&"'
and C <> '"&AP64&"'
and C <> '"&AP65&"'
and C <> '"&AP66&"'
and C <> '"&AP67&"'
and C <> '"&AP68&"'
and C <> '"&AP69&"'
and C <> '"&AP70&"'

and AC <> '"&AQ2&"'
and AC <> '"&AQ3&"'
and AC <> '"&AQ4&"'
and AC <> '"&AQ5&"'

and U <> '"&AR2&"'
and U <> '"&AR3&"'
and U <> '"&AR4&"'
and U <> '"&AR5&"'

and M <> '"&AS2&"'
and M <> '"&AS3&"'
and M <> '"&AS4&"'
and M <> '"&AS5&"'
and M <> '"&AS6&"'
and M <> '"&AS7&"'
and M <> '"&AS8&"'
and M <> '"&AS9&"'
and M <> '"&AS10&"'
and M <> '"&AS11&"'
"
)
```

This is going to let my dynamically edit my sheet instead of going into a formula and editing 50+ sumifs functions. However, I'm stuck here because now I have a column O:O that I need to be able to say.. select if the cell contains text from AO3 OR AO4 OR AO5 etc.etc. as well as does not contain all of the information I've already input.

What I have in my formula thus far basically excludes all the information that I don't want, but now I need to input information that I DO want.

Here's the spreadsheet I'm working on now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZYzLWIXeNR6R9ugAiTmRcXEshJBZDpN_xWCAumpJujY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The post lacks a clearly specified _question_. Consider showing your _manually entered_ desired results in the sample spreadsheet. For completeness, post a reasonable amount of representative sample data as a table directly in the question, together with your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will get the same results as your monster `query()` and should be easier to manage:

```
=filter( 
  { C2:C, F2:F, I2:I, M2:M, O2:O, P2:P, S2:S, U2:U, Y2:Y, AC2:AC, AJ2:AJ, AK2:AK }, 
  isna(match(C2:C, AP2:AP, 0)), 
  isna(match(M2:M, AS2:AS, 0)), 
  isna(match(U2:U, AR2:AR, 0)), 
  isna(match(AC2:AC, AQ2:AQ, 0)) 
)
```

To add a condition like "column `O2:O` contains a value that appears in column `ZZ2:ZZ`", use the same pattern, but without the `isna()`. To implement an "or" condition, use [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra).

Comment: @doulbeunary This is really helpful, thank you! Only issue I'm having now is inputting the Booblean logic. So I've filtered for answers based on...

=filter( 
  { C2:C, F2:F, I2:I, M2:M, O2:O, P2:P, S2:S, U2:U, Y2:Y, AC2:AC, AJ2:AJ, AK2:AK }, 
  isna(match(C2:C, AP2:AP, 0)), 
  isna(match(M2:M, AS2:AS, 0)), 
  isna(match(U2:U, AR2:AR, 0)), 
  isna(match(AC2:AC, AQ2:AQ, 0)),
  match(M2:M,AN2:AN,0) (added this)

However, I'm now trying to add another filter to it using (+); however, it's not working and it's giving me

"FILTER range must be a single row or a single column."

Comment: Use this pattern `=filter( C2:C, match(M2:M, BM2:BM, 0) + match(N2:N, BN2:BN, 0) )`. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your help @doubleunary!